# Get custom field ACF in custom menu

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a menu in Wordpress with an ACF field called "svg"

To create my menu, I do this:

```
function b_get_menu_id( $location )
{
  $a = get_nav_menu_locations();
  if (isset($a[$location])) return $a[$location];
  return false;
}

function b_get_nav_items($location) {
  $id = b_get_menu_id($location);
  $nav = [];
  $children = [];
  if(!$id) {
    return $nav;
  }
  foreach(wp_get_nav_menu_items($id) as $object) {
    $item = new stdClass();
    $item->url = $object->url;
    $item->label = $object->title;
    $item->id = $object->object_id;
    $item->icon = $object->classes[0];
    $item->parent = intval($object->menu_item_parent);
    $item->children = [];
    if($item->parent){
      $children[] = $item;
    } else {
      $nav[$object->ID] = $item;
    }
  }
  foreach($children as $item) {
    $nav[$item->parent]->children[] = $item;
  }
  return $nav;
}
```

I display my menu like this:

```
@foreach(b_get_nav_items('primary_navigation') as $item)
... my html here...
@endforeach
```

In my foreach, I'm trying to call my ACF fields from my menu like this:

```
<?php get_field('svg', $item->id)
```

But it does not work (null). I'm lost. How can I get my ACF field?

thank you so much

Comment: is the field saved on the menu, or on the menu item?

Comment: see if you can get your field `var_dump(get_fields($item->id));` maybe?

Comment: The field is saved on the menu item, get_field($item) doesn't work (Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string). Thank you for your help

Comment: yeah sorry - you needed the id - I edited that

Comment: I tried <?php var_dump(get_fields($item->id)); ?>, but return false

Comment: weird - in the documentation, you should be able to do it like that - even though they do it through a filter : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not documented [in the ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/), but this seems to work if you prefix with "menu_". For example:

`get_field('field_name', 'menu_' . $menu_id);`

Answer (score 0):

update: It's documented [in the ACF docs](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-to-display-a-nav-menu-field-without-wp_nav_menu/)

WordPress > 4.4

`get_field('field_name', 'term_' . $menu_id);`

WordPress < 4.4

`get_field('field_name', 'nav_menu_' . $menu_id);`